# How can I divide streetnr and street out of one String?

Tags: php

I want to divide an String into var street and streetnr. How can I do this with php?

The data look like:

```
Bakerstreet 5
Wild Street 5 a
Best Street 5a
Simplestreet
```

I have Streets without numbers and Streets with letters ... How can I do this?

So the street should always be like

var street = Bakerstreet, Wild Street, Best Street, Simplestreet

var streetnr should always be = 5, 5 a, 5a

My idea was to explode the string after every blank " " ... Then I reverse the array and look if the first element is just a letter. If it is, I put it into streetnr. Then I check the next element. If there are just numbers, I put it into streetnr ... and so on

Comment: So, before you get to a solution, you really need to define your criteria for how you determine the "street" part vs. the "street number". Can you explain the requirements in real world terms?

Comment: Ok I edited the question, sry for that!

Comment: @Susanne92 - and are they always going to be in that format? You're not going to have any lines where the street number is first, followed by the name of the street?

Comment: you can try to find the first number [0-9] in string and take the substring from zero to the given position

Comment: @Susanne92 You edited the question, but you still haven't commented on what the actual logic is that you intend to use to split the parts.

Comment: Would break on `1st St 52b`

Comment: @steven What would happen for the case of address like `1st Street 100`? You might not be able to go on first number occurrence. Then again we don't really know as neither the logic for splitting nor any commentary on the expected data variations have been described.

Comment: @Susanne92 I hope you see where the comments are headed here. In your mind this might seem like a simple problem, but it can be VERY complex depending on the variability of the data and what actual human logic you are trying to reproduce in code.  My suggestions would be to really spend some time thinking on those aspects so you can try to narrow down the problem.

Comment: @MikeBrant: Look at the regular expression posted, it covers your 'complex problems'.

Comment: Another wrinkle: Streets can have unadorned numbers in their names (e.g, "Road 17"). I'm not certain there's any good way to parse these without knowing what street names exist around the target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used this as an excercise for my PHP-Training. And while I'm a huge fan of regex, I wanted to do it without em and came up with the following:

```
<?php
$addr = array("Bakerstreet 5",
"Wild Street 5 a",
"Best Street 5a",
"Simplestreet",
"Won't Work 47a Suite 18b",
"1st Street 10b ",
"Route 66 12a " 
);


echo "<h1>Address-Parsing</h1><ol>";
foreach ($addr as $ad) 
{
  $no=""; // Number
  $st=""; // Street
  $GotNo = false;
  $r = strrev(trim($ad));
  echo "<li>ad=$ad";
  do {
    while ($r{0}=="0") {// special handling for leading "0"s (in reverted string) which are ignored by sscanf...
        if (!$GotNo) $no = "0" . $no;
        else $st = "0" . $st;
        $r = substr($r,1);
    }
    $d = sscanf($r,"%d"); // get number
    $s = sscanf($r,"%c"); // get string
    if (is_null($d[0]) && !$GotNo) {
      // no matching number and have not matched no yet - so this must be string following the nr
      $no = strrev($s[0]) . $no;
      $r = substr($r,strlen($s[0])); // remove match
    } elseif (!$GotNo) {
      $no = strrev($d[0]) . $no;
      $GotNo = true;
      $r = substr($r,strlen($d[0])); // remove match
    } else {// we already have a number, so any text must be streetname
      $st = strrev($r) . $st;
      $r="";
    }
    if ($r !== trim($r)) {$st = " " . $st; $r = trim($r);}
  } while (0<strlen($r));
  $st = trim( $st);
  if (empty($st)) {// might happen when no number was found...
    $st=$no;
    $no="";
  }
  echo "|st=$st|no=$no|</li>";
}
echo "</ol>";

 ?>
```

Comment: What does happen in these cases? `1st Street 10b` `Route 66 12a`

Comment: Here is some unquestioned advice for you PHP training: Use meaningful variable names for *everything* that is not a simple loop counter. And even there if the counter has a special meaning. Otherwise colleagues will hate you, you won't be able to understand your own code and the gates of hell will open!

Comment: @STTLCU: you'd get |st=1st Street|no=10b| (I had to fix a bug there, thanks for that!)and |st=Route 66|no=12a|

Comment: glad to have helped :)

Comment: @MartinThurau: oh well, opening the gates of hell is certainly something I would not like being accused of - will try to use longer meaningful names nxt time :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular Expression

```
preg_match('~^\s*(.*)\s+([0-9]+\s*[a-zA-Z]{0,1})\s*$~', $street, $match);
```

preg_match returns true if the street is in the right format and $match is an array containing [1]=street name, [2]=streetnr.

Answer (score 0):

You could match using the following regular expression:

```
preg_match('/^(.+?)(?:\s+(\d.*))?$/', $street, $matches);
$street = $matches[1];
if (count($matches) == 3)
  $streetnr = $matches[2];
```